# How can I know which sheet changed of a Google spreadsheet via AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script

Dear Google AppScript Experts,

Recentlly I'm wondering whether there is a way to know exactly which sheet of a google spreadsheet changed or not. For example, thera are 30 sheets, such as 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3' and etc.

I can use Google Drive AppScript to retrieve the last update timestamp of spreadsheet to know whether it's changed or not, which it's on the whole spreadsheet, I cannot get to know which sheet change.

Anyone who has a solution on this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's well documented: [GAS-triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Use the OnChange trigger and the 'e' object will have the 'source' with the spreadsheet name. Even though the doc doesn't mention it, you can use source with OnChange as well as OnEdit.